# Joomla Menu-Alias more than once

Tags: joomla

I'm trying to have a main menu and a sitemap menu in the footer of my site

so the links in the main menu should repeat in the footer.
there's only one layer.

so it's:

```
mysite.com/home/
mysite.com/artical1/
mysite.com/artical2/
```

and so on.

i get an error message if i try to use the same alias in a different menu (or in a second menu)

"Save failed with the following error: Another menu item has the same alias in Root. Root is the top level parent"

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

when you create the duplicate menu, give it a unique title. Tell it to hide the menu title when you create the module.

When you create each menu item, choose Menu Item Alias under System Links, as you menu type.

Don't fill in the alias. The system will fill it in for you with the date and time. This way, each duplicate menu item will have a unique alias.

Enjoy..

Comment: Thanks, got stuck on this one - it's your Menu Item Alias that solved it.